# Constrains on the coefficients of SARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, constraint, synthetic-data

I am trying to generate synthetic time-series through SARIMA random process by defining the model coefficients manually. Could any one help me how to generate coefficients? What are the constraints on the SARIMA coefficients?

Thanks

Comment: Write out the model equation explicitly, and you will see that some coefficients are pairwise products of other coefficients. You just have to ensure this feature in choosing the coefficients yourself.

Comment: How about stationary constraints?

Comment: Right, there are those, too.